# date_default_timezone_set not available to crond

Tags: php, cron

When I call my php skript from the browser, it runs fine. When I call it through a cronjob, it returns this error:

```
Call to undefined function: date_default_timezone_set
```

Why? And how do I set the timezone properly?

Comment: can you please set timezone from htaccess file ? It will resolve your issue. Please check [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/htacess-change-timezone)

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia How?

Comment: Please check link from above comment.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia Oops, thank you. I didn't notice the link.

Comment: Hope that link will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')
{
   date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
}
```

Comment: But how do I set the timezone, if the function does not exist?

Comment: what is your php version?

Comment: try this in you php ini ini_set( 'date.timezone', 'UTC' );

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).